# How would one disable audio/video sync in webrtcbin?

Tags: gstreamer

I noticed very high `ts-offsets` in the jitter buffers within `webrtcbin`. My understanding is that this timestamp offset is used to sync audio and video.

Is there a way to disable audio/video sync in webrtcin, as to not incur this latency?

```
rtp-jitter-buffer [rtpjitterbuffer1] offset: 0 
rtp-jitter-buffer [rtpjitterbuffer0] offset: 0 
rtp-jitter-buffer [rtpjitterbuffer3] offset: 30449551 
rtp-jitter-buffer [rtpjitterbuffer2] offset: 0 
rtp-jitter-buffer [rtpjitterbuffer1] offset: 0 
rtp-jitter-buffer [rtpjitterbuffer0] offset: 908079013 
rtp-jitter-buffer [rtpjitterbuffer3] offset: 30449551
```